# DataGridView with images from XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

say that I was to store image paths in an xml file. What I want to do is display the image in a DataGridView depending on the status stored in my sql server database table. Therefore, if I was to add a new project, I would store 'IN PROGRESS' in my Project table under STATUS. What I would like to do is display progress.png in my DataGridView. Likewise, if I was to change the status from IN PROGRESS to COMPLETED, I want to display complete.png. I am only working with two images, so let me know what the best way to go around doing this would be. Sample code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<images>
<pic>
    <image>images/progress.png</image>
    <caption>In Progress</caption>
</pic>
<pic>
    <image>images/complete.png</image>
    <caption>Completed</caption>
</pic>
</images>
```

Comment: Static stuff like this I personally like to embed into the assembly as a resource. Please let me know if this would be a good alternative for you, if yes I give an example

Answer (score 0):

use Lambada expressions to match the conditions from the XMl file and SQL database.
Here is a sample walk through.

```
var imageList = Imagelist.Where(x => x.Status ==status).FirstOrDefault().ToList();
```

where Imagelist is a list of images populated from XML file. and status is the set of status from your SQL database.

add the Image filename in your dataset or datasource you use to power your Gridview.

In the  tag of your grid view just add this code

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/'<%# Eval("FileName") %>'" Width="100px" Height="100px" />
```